# What is the easiest way to maximise your drop rate?

Tags: ps3, dark-souls

I often find that my drop rates are really low is the best way to increase it to gain lots of humanity and stay human or is it to constantly have the Gold covetous Serpent ring equipped? is there any other items that increase your drop rate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two that you've listed are your best bet.  Your best drop rate is going to be a 410.  You can get it up to 210 with a humanity of 10 (which is the max humanity that will be put to your drop rate).  The Gold Serpent Ring can get that to 410.  The Symbol of Avarice does the same.  You can find all of this on the Dark Souls wiki [here](http://darksoulswiki.wikispaces.com/Humanity).

Comment: ah so if I equip both the ring and the symbol of avarice will it still stay as 410?

Comment: From both my experience and what I've read on the internet, yes.  It does not stack with the Ring.  However, the Symbol of Avarice does give you an increased soul drop rate as well, at the cost of your health, so you might want it on for grinding purposes.

Comment: The Symbol of Avarice absolutely does not stack with the ring. As stated, highest drop rate is Gold Serpent Ring +10 Humanity.

Comment: This being said, I think most humanity scaling attributes of the game seem to cap at 10 Humanity. This goes for Weapon Scaling & Drop Rate. The only benefit for humanity 11-99 is Curse Resist, (and looking badass).

Comment: What exactly does 410 drop rate mean? Is it +410%, so item which had 10% will now have 51% (10 + 4.1*10) to drop? Or is the base drop 100, so 10% will become 31% (10 * 4.1)?